# c for looping with i and j

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm beginer and I'm trying to understand this guys,if someome could explain me this I'd be grateful.

so here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
   int i, 
       j, 
       a = 2, 
       b = 2;

   for( i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
      for( j = 3; j < 5; j++ ) {
         a = a + b;
      }
   }

   printf( "a=%d", a );
}
```

Comment: What **specifically** don't you understand?

Comment: With correct indentation, it will help (thanks to LPs). Also, using brackets `{` and `}` it also helps

Comment: Well how will this 2 loops affect variable a,step by step

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pencil, and step trough the code manually keeping track of variables.

Comment: Step 1-4: `a=a+b`

Comment: Also, learn to use a debugger, it's a very useful tools to learn programming (and sometime to find bug) ;) it will show you how second loop is repeating 2 times and how `a=a+b` is repeat 2 * 2 times

Answer (score 4):

Run this code and check the output:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i, j, a=2, b=2;

   for( i=1; i<3; i++) {
      for( j=3; j<5; j++) {
         a=a+b;
         printf("inner: when i=%d, j=%d, a=%d\n", i, j, a);
      }
   }

   printf("a=%d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: thank you man,that was very useful for understanding and I'm sure it will be in future too!

Answer (score 1):

```
   for( i=1; i<3; i++)
      for( j=3; j<5; j++)
          a=a+b;
```

Here first loop iterates two times (i=1,2) and second loop iterates also two times (j=3,4). Total four times `a` is incremented by `b`.

That means, after iteration completes, a will be 2 + b*4. So, a = 2 + 8 = 10.

Comment: thank you very much dude

Comment: Learn loop and practice to know it deeply.